# Can I connect to remote DB server from inside docker container?

Tags: docker

My app is running against a mssql server 2012 or above,

I tried to set up 2 containers - 1 for my app and one to be a DB server.

But I couldn't use the DB container due to mssql server version windows image is not supported by my app.

So I'm want to connect to a remote DB server that I have which is a different server than the Docker host.

How do I get the container to ping the remote DB server?

***From the container-***

```
C:\Installation>ping  my0134.company.net
Ping request could not find host my0134.company.net. Please check the name and try again.
```

** NOTE - I am using Docker on windows

Comment: what happens when you ping by ip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could try adding `<IP of my0134.company.net> my0134.company.net` to the `etc/hosts` file. This way the url can be resolved to a IP address. You can also just use

`docker run --add-host 'my0134.company.net':<IP of my0134.company.net> <image>`

to spin up your container.

Comment: what if `my0134.company.net` is a VIP and doesnt have a static IP address?

Answer (score 0):

If IPV4 forwarding is enabled then container can connect to DB Server.There is no issue with that.

Comment: Ipv4 inside the container or on the docker host

Comment: Ipv4 on docker host.If the host running docker doesn't have IP forwarding, then the container won't have access to the outside world.After enabling ipv4 forwarding on docker host, restart docker service.

Comment: Sorry to resurrect a real old question.Is this solved? i am using --net host ,so all host ports should be shared.but still cannot ping out side hosts.